# How to register md-icon (Material2) to be used throughout different modules and components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have 3 modules in my app and I want to render icons in different html pages. I have a assets folder where i have icon-set.svg file.

Currently i am able to render icons in my app.component.html page by registering 
mdIconRegistry in app.module.ts file.

```
export class AppModule {
constructor(private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, private sanitizer: 
DomSanitizer) {

    mdIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('settings',sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/settings.svg'))
 }
}
```

I wish to render icons in another html page which resides in module namely navbar.module.ts.
Icons are not getting rendered in navbar.component.html after registering mdIconRegistry in app.module.ts.

I have to explicitly write constructor code again in navabar.module.ts as shown below to get desired output.

```
 export class NavbarModule {
 constructor(private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, private sanitizer: 
DomSanitizer) {

  mdIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('settings',sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/settings.svg'))

}
 }
```

Is there a better way to do thsi globally rather than re-writng constructor code again and again for different mdoules.

Answer (score 0):

Just register your icon at your `AppModule`:

```ts
@NgModule([
    imports: [
        MdIconModule
    ]
])
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        mdIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('settings', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/images/icons/settings.svg'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this. But i am not able to access this settings icon my other module. I have created a navbar module.I cant access it there.

Comment: yes.. also have registered MdIconRegistry in app.module.ts providers

Comment: You don't need to register `MdIconRegistry` as a provider!

Comment: I removed that, but still unable to see icons in different modules, unless i register them again in respective modules.

Answer (score 0):

What i've done is to register the icon in my **app.component.ts** as follows:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private mdIconRegistry: MdIconRegistry,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mdIconRegistry.addSvgIconInNamespace('namespace', 'icon-name',
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('path-to-icon.svg')
    );
  }

}
```

In my **app.module.ts** im importing **MdIconModule**, but you also have to import **MdIconModule** in each of your submodules (no need to register custom icons again)

You can consider having a **SharedModule** that imports/exports the material components, and only import this new **SharedModule** in each of your submodules (including **app.module**)